# Sending data over serial port

Tags: c, serial-port

I am trying to send data over serial port programmatically. I have an embedded system which runs Linux. On the bootloader prompt, I intend to stop execution by pressing CTRL+C and modifying the boot args. I am able to send the CTRL+C character and the booting does stop. However when I try to send a big command over serial port using the write(), it doesn't seem to be succeeding. Any inputs on what could be wrong? Below is my code snippet:

```
int main() {
  // Open the serial port. Change device path as needed (currently set to an standard FTDI USB-UART cable type device)
  int serial_port = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR);

  // Create new termios struc, we call it 'tty' for convention
  struct termios tty;
  char data = 0x03; 
  char data2[]={'r','u','n',' ', 'l','o','a','d','b','o','o','t','e','n','v','\r'};
  char data4[]= "setenv mmcargs \'setenv bootargs console=ttyO0,115200n8 console=tty0 ${optargs} 
  root=/dev/mmcblk1p3 rootfstype=ext4 panic=1\';

  // Read in existing settings, and handle any error
  if(tcgetattr(serial_port, &tty) != 0) {
      printf("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
      return 1;
  }

  tty.c_cflag  = CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
  tty.c_iflag = IGNBRK | IGNPAR;
  tty.c_oflag = OPOST;
  tty.c_lflag = 0;
  tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
  tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
  tcflush(serial_port, TCIFLUSH);

  // Set in/out baud rate to be 115200
  cfsetispeed(&tty, B115200);
  cfsetospeed(&tty, B115200);

  // Save tty settings, also checking for error
  if (tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
      printf("Error %i from tcsetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
      return 1;
  }

   write(serial_port, &data, 1);
   ret = write(serial_port, &data2, sizeof(data2));
   ret = write(serial_port, &data4, sizeof(data4));
```

All the writes succeed (this i verified by returned value) but then the write corresponding to data4 doesn't succeed in generating a response. When I simultaneously run minicom, I see that only 27 bytes of the final write are actually written. Not sure what is wrong.

If I give the same command as in data4 using putty, it succeeds without any issue. The settings on putty were speed(baud): 115200
Databits: 8
Stopbits: 1
Parity: NONE
Flowcontrol: NONE

Can someone help me where I am going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: please check your code. I thought highlight.js was bugging here but it is a copy-paste error in your code.

Comment: How is the embedded system connected after the USB connection? Is there a "real" serial line? If so, did you try to watch the transmission with an oscilloscope? You might like to look for the intervals between the characters, perhaps the target is overrun.

Comment: Yes, its a real serial line. What options could be used to set the interval between the characters

Comment: First you need to make sure that the target is actually overrun. Only then you need to think about setting intervals. As your control system seems to be Linux, too, you might like to look up `usleep()`. I don't know if there is also an option in `struct termios`.

Comment: *"Can someone help me where I am going wrong?"* -- (1) Your termios initialization (or what you copied) is problematic.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237).  (2) OPOST is enabled, which is a peculiar choice. (3) Three sequential **write()** statements without querying (i.e. reading) the target for response(s) is probably ill-advised.  When you *"give the same command ... using putty"* that is an interactive mode with pauses.  Your program has no such pauses.

Comment: (4) The initialization of **data4[]** seems to encompass much more than intended.

Comment: @sawdust could you help suggest any reference code in C language for automating the interactive mode programmatically.

Comment: In interactive mode, you respond when a *prompt* appears.  So your program needs to read, and scan for the prompt before sending a command with the **write()**.   Seems like you're interacting with U-Boot.  The sending of the Ctrl-C would have to be synchronized with the processor reset & prompt, but your code is simple and does no waiting.  How does that work?